# reorder html inside multiple divs (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery to make modifications to an otherwise-uneditable page. The page contains several `container` elements in this format:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="A"></div>
    <div class="B">
        <div class="C"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="D"></div>
</div>
```

For each `container`, I want to move the content so that `A` is inside of `B`, like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="B">
        <div class="C"></div>
        <div class="A"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="D"></div>
</div>
```

What's the best way to do this with jQuery? Every solution I can think of would only work for a single `container` element, as opposed to modifying them all.

Comment: are there any other instances of `class="A"`?

Comment: @roullie No, there aren't.

Comment: try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/roullie666/ok6rbdpo/). with multiple containers as example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.container').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.A').appendTo($(this).find('.B'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
$('.container .A').each(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.B').append($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **MOVE** that element,not **COPY** as you said in your question.

```
$('.container').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.A').detach().appendTo($(this).find('.B'));
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tgnk7mLv/1/)

Comment: You don't need to call detach before appendTo, its done automatically.